# Redirecting POST using CURL and basic realm AUTH only once

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, post

User is submitting a form on page A that has **action="https://siteB"**, on site B I have php script that does basic real auth and is using $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] to create destination URL

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="test"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'message';
    exit;
} 

else 

{
    
$login = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
$url = 'https://siteB/'.$login.'/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:".$url."");    
exit;

}

?>
```

**siteB/login/index.php** is destination page that displays POST and where in the same folder .htaccess is placed for auth

I want user to input login/passwd only once but right now it is not working

If I enter siteB directly and auth then it redirects to siteB/login flawlessly but if that same page siteB is loaded as a result of form submit then I auth once and it asks again for auth when it loads siteB/login/index.php

there is also an issue with passing POST fields but temp redirect 307 works fine and if I can configure form to submit **action="https://siteB/login"** then it asks me only once for auth but I need action to point only to "https://siteB" and then redirect; separate htaccess for every user is also welcomed

right now the only solution I see it to reconfigure https://siteB/ to receive POST, ask user for login/passwd and submit new form to https://siteB/login/

Comment: Your whole description is a bit confusing, I can’t really tell what sense the whole approach is supposed to make. But if you make the request that passes the credentials to site B via cURL _on your server_, then who you actually authenticated with B, _is_ your server. If you now make a request for site B in your _browser_ afterwards, then of course it will ask your for the credentials - because your _browser_ has not authenticated itself with B, only your server did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply speaking what I wanted to achieve is to submit form on page A to page B, page B is asking for credentials and uses login as a part of URL for redirection to page C, page C is accepting header with AUTH and is displaying submitted form; previously it was asking twice for credentials but I managed to modify code as follows so it asks for credentials only once

```
$login = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

$url = 'https://siteC/'.$login.'/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  

header("Location:".$url."",TRUE,307);
exit;
```